# R packages for multivariate Bernstein copulas

Tags: r, r-package, copula

Does anyone know if there exist packages to fit multivariate Bernstein copula in R. I have searched, and I only find a couple of packages for bivariate copula (kdecopula, subcopem2D). since this is a rather popular non-parametric copula, I would assume such a package exist in R, but I have not been able to find it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think `vinereg` has non-parametric regression copula models.

Answer (score 0):

I think np package has nonparametric copula. But if you found other packages with more than two dimensions reply here please.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there are two `R` functions as follows:

`rvinecopulib`: covers bivariate and multivariate (vine) copula models. It also takes into account both parametric and non-parametric copula.

`vinereg`: provides `D-vine copula` regression models, including non-parametric copula families.